# Mysterious C:\Users\cwilson folder in Windows

Tags: windows-7, security, macbook-pro

I'm worried that my Windows computer was compromised, because I am the sole owner, and I recently came across a strange folder on my computer. `C:\Users\cwilson\`.

Either someone created their own account on my computer, or possibly some software I installed used a bad default setting for the current user. Dunno which.

Specs:

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: What is the date and file structure of that folder? Also consider searching through your registry for that name to see if any software will stand out.

Comment: Did you buy that computer new yourself? Did you buy it mail order or through a small shop? Who installed the OS for you? Do/did you have someone doing maintenance? Give us its history.

Comment: @JanDoggen I bought my computer straight from Apple and installed Windows myself.

Comment: cwilson is the ghost of a long lost Apple employee who met an ill fate after installing Windows on a Mac... :) What is the date of last modification and created date in that folder's properties? Perhaps you can match that date/time up with recently installed software.